# Add figures in new subplot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, figure

I have two lists, `plot_list_1` and `plot_list_2`, with same length `n`.

These lists consists of `matplotlib` `figure` objects in `Python`.

So, I can do something like this to see the figures:

`plot_list_1[0].get_figure()`

`plot_list_2[0].get_figure()`

I wanted to make a list `plot_twist` of subplots with dimension `n x 2`, so that I could do:

`plot_twist[0].get_figure()`

and visualize two figures, one from `plot_list_1[0].get_figure()` and other from `plot_list_2[0].get_figure()`, side by side.

Is it possible to make a list of subplots, each plot extracted from one of my `figure` lists, and then use `get_figure()` or an equivalent command to see these two figures?

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to plot axes instances from different figure instances in the same figure?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want!